# Unable to map array of positions with useGLTF

Tags: reactjs, typescript, three.js, react-three-fiber, tsx

I was using `gltfjsx` to convert all my models `glb/gltf` files into `jsx/tsx` components then using it. But the problem is `gltfjsx` is giving me more than 3k- 4k lines of code for a single component. So I tried using `useGLTF` from `drei` directly. like this

```js
import { useGLTF } from "@react-three/drei";

const Dummy = () => {
  const { scene } = useGLTF("/dummy.glb");
  return <primitive object={scene} />;
};

export { Dummy };
```

and then rendered it like this:

```js
 {DummyArray.map((currentPos, index) => {
  return (
<RigidBody lockRotations key={index}>
   <Dummy position={currentPos} />
</RigidBody>
 );
 })}
```

previously with `gltfjsx` I was seeing as many copies of `Dummy component` as there were elements (positions) in the array but now when I'm using `useGLTF` I only see one copy.

Comment: you don't use the prop `position` passed to the Dummy component inside it. Try with 

`const Dummy = ({position}) => {` and then
`return <primitive object={scene} position={position} />;`

Comment: Nope,still seeing the same. You can check it out at this sandbox:  https://codesandbox.io/s/rapier-practice-1prxoq?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: you need to clone the scene Object3D otherwise it's cached and is the same instance in all Dummy components : `const clonedObj = useMemo(() => scene.clone(), [scene]);` and use `clonedObj` as the primitive object